# How to Auto Generate Kotlin Class Name to match new Kotlin File in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

When creating a new Java file in Android Studio, the file automatically contains the boilerplate code required. Example:

> package com.testproject.test
>
> public class TestClass { 
>   }

When I make a new Kotlin file in Android studio, it only contains the following auto generated code but it doesn't contain the class:

> package com.testproject.test

So I have to type the class every time.

I understand that the classes in Kotlin are not required to be named the same as their containing file, but it's still an accepted convention.

Is there a way to tell Android Studio to generate the class name with the same as the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a new Kotlin File/Class just select Class from the dropdown:

[image]

Comment: I see. I need to change the selection from "File" to "Class"! Thanks!